# How to preserve dropdown data after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am binding dropdown at client side using Jquery. I am fetching data from server using PageMethods.

**html**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                  onchange="return country_changed();" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**JS**

```
function GetCountryLst() {
    PageMethods.GetCountryList(OnsuccessCountry);
    return false;
}

function OnsuccessCountry(result) {
    $("#ddlCountry").append("<option value='Select'>Select</option>");
    for (var eachval in result) {
         $("#ddlCountry").append("<option value='" + result[eachval].id + "'>" + result[eachval].name + "</option>");
    }
    return false;
}
```

On button click when i write

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddlcount = ddlCountry.Items.Count;
}
```

I get ddlCount = 0; How can i preserve the data

Comment: r u using update panel ?

Comment: no i am not using updatepanel. but, i dont mind using it if i get the values at server side

Comment: you want only count or all values also?

Comment: i think update panel can solve your problem

Comment: all values but if the count is 0 how can i get the values

Comment: I think u should fetch with hidden field using Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type='hidden' id='items' />

function OnsuccessCountry(result) {
    $("#ddlCountry").append("<option value='Select'>Select</option>");
    for (var eachval in result) {
         $("#ddlCountry").append("<option value='" + result[eachval].id + "'>" + result[eachval].name + "</option>");

    $("#items").val($("#items").val() + ";" + result[eachval].id) ;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And split (with ; ) the value of this hidden field at server side and get count and all items also..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Page method to fill data you can't get the dropdown list items count from server side. Because it will be cleared when Page_load event happens.

Comment: @ Ulhas Tuscano : all items of DropDownList stored in ViewState but on calling of page method ViewState doesn't render

Comment: no way if u fill textbox at clientside(javascript) using pagemethod. I get the textbox value at server even after postback

Comment: @Ulhas : nothing wrong with Page methods. (I don't think I said something like that in the answer.) Why because the Page_load event works before Button_Click event, which will reset all the Page contents, so you will lost something which is not in the View state.